# Parsing unknown POST args in PHP

Tags: php, html, post

I have an HTML form being populated by a table of customer requests. The user reviews each request, sets an operation, and submits. The operation gets set into a POST arg as follow

```
$postArray = array_keys($_POST);

[1]=>Keep [2]=>Reject [3]=>Reject [4]=>Ignore ["item id"]=>"operation"
```

This is how I am parsing my POST args, it seems awkward, the unused `$idx`. I am new to PHP, is there a smoother way to do this?

```
$postArray = array_keys($_POST);            
foreach($postArray as $idx => $itemId) {            
    $operation = $_POST[$itemId];
    echo "$itemId $operation </br>";
    // ...perform operation...
}
```

Comment: How can `array_keys` produce duplicates?

Comment: @webbiedave: I'm sure he just shown the raw values of `$_POST` (non-numeric and non-continuous keys confirm that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) // $key will contain the name of the array key
```

Comment: @Endophage: Thanks but please don't edit posts younger than 5 minutes. The author is most likely still editing :)

Comment: I'll give authors time to edit based on the length of the post... Long post, I'll give more leeway time for editing... Incidentally, wasn't me that voted you down...

Comment: @Endophage am I having a moment, or was the "typo" you "fixed" removing the space between `foreach` and `(`?

Comment: @Corbin no, webbie has typed `$_PSOT` rather than `$_POST`

Comment: @Endophage Revision 1 shows `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)` as the content?

Comment: @Corbin: Endophage is correct. I misspelled POST and that's what he changed.

Comment: @Endophage: That's also why editing someone else's post that is only a minute old can be bad (leads to confusion in the editing history) :)

Comment: @webbiedave That's what I figured happened, but I decided to drop it for fear that I was becoming too combative.  (Only commented in the first place because I can't stand when people edit in the first minute or two of an answer).  :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
foreach($_POST as $itemId => $operation ) {            
    echo "$itemId $operation </br>";
    // ...perform operation...
}
```

instead

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use $idx in loop if is not needed.
It might be like that:

```
foreach($postArray as $itemId) { 
...
}
```

Main problem is the data structure is very messy.
Maybe it's better way to organise form output.
Probably in some well structured associative array.
I can't see the form, I don't know the details so it's hard to tell more.